# It is possible to prevent people to know that I'm on Viber?

Tags: windows, android, viber

So I'm on [Viber](https://www.viber.com/en/), now everybody on my contacts `(and probably who has my contact even they're not on my contact)` who's in Viber know that I'm on Viber too and they can send me private messages or can call me anytime. I simply block those people, I used Viber only for the sake of my family, and I only want them to contact me on Viber.

Everything's fine with me because whoever calls me if they're not part of my family, then BLOCK is the key. But then today somebody called me, I don't know this person but for some reason, the phone number is saved on my contact. I blocked this person, but since he knows my number, he used another Viber account and send me another message, and called me.

So, It is possible to prevent people to know that I'm on Viber to prevent this scenario? This thing probably won't happen if they don't know that I'm on Viber.

Comment: You can hide your online status from the settings. But no, you can't prevent those people who's in your contact nor the people who has your contact from knowing you're in Viber. This is one of the problem for both WhatsApp and Viber application, "talking about privacy". I switched to Facebook Messenger, it has an option to determine who's in Messenger base on your contact, well at least you can disabled it.

Comment: Oh crap, I wish there was a feature to disabled it like Facebook Messenger. I used Facebook Messenger but only for chatting with my friends and soon. I feel safe to Viber when chatting to my family with it. Anyway, I'll try looking for an alternative application that has this kind of feature. I don't want to switch with Facebook Messenger.